# Error while creating Android APK in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, apk

While generating APK from Visual Studio 2017 for Xamarin Android, I am getting the following error.
"Please ensure that you are using a release configuration and that the use shared mono runtime"

Unable to find this option in Android build configurations.

Comment: I did not understand the reason for downvote?

Comment: try cleaning project , delete bin/obj folders and rebuild ! this should solve the problem

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the issue by **Uncheck** Use Shared Runtime in Android Options.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the project properties and mark "use shared runtime" and also set your build config. to release